# Unable to handle cell size dynamically, According to content size

Tags: swift, string, uitableview, uifont

I am trying to change tableView cell height dynamically according to content size, But getting error.

**Error-**

[image]

**Actual Code-**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        let height:CGFloat = self.calculateHeightForString(downloadTableDataa[indexPath.row] as! String)
        return height + 70.0
    }

    func calculateHeightForString(inString:String) -> CGFloat
    {
        let messageString = inString
        let attributes =  UIFont.init(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 15)

        let attrString:NSAttributedString? = NSAttributedString(string: messageString, attributes: attributes)
        let rect:CGRect = attrString!.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(300.0,CGFloat.max), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, context:nil )//hear u will get nearer height not the exact value
        let requredSize:CGRect = rect
        return requredSize.height  //to include button's in your tableview

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to pass an object of type UIFont into the attributes field, and the attributes field is expecting a dictionary of type [String:AnyObject]. That's what the error is telling you.

**Before**

```
let attributes = UIFont.init(name:"Roboto-Regular", size:15.0) <---- UIFont
let attrString:NSAttributedString? = NSAttributedString(string: messageString, attributes: attributes) <---- wants a dictionary of type [String:AnyObject]
```

**After**

```
let stringAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 18.0)!] 
let attrString = NSAttributedString(string: messageString, attributes: stringAttributes)
```

Comment: `Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' (0x10a7dff98) to 'NSString' (0x109abab48).`

Comment: **In the line-**         `let height:CGFloat = self.calculateHeightForString(downloadTableDataa[indexPath.row] as! String)`

Comment: can you show your calculateHeightForString method please?

Comment: and where you declare your downloadTableDataa array

Comment: without seeing those, it appears as if the object at downloadTableDataa[indexpath.row] is an NSDictionary that you're trying to force cast using "as!" to NSString....you can't convert a dictionary to a string

Comment: If you're trying to create dynamic tableview cells based on content check out this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells ....You basically just use autolayout, and then set tableView.rowHeight - UITableViewAutomaticDimension, and tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0 (something close to an average of what you expect)

Comment: `let downloadTableDataa = SharedPreferenceUtil.getNSObject("downloadDataNSObject") as! NSArray`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127078/discussion-between-ideveloper-and-user3353890).